# A more efficient way to group, sum and calculate a SQL statement

Tags: mysql

Is there a more efficient way (processor time) to write this statement?

```
SELECT student_year, 
    student_id, 
    sum(score_0)/sum(exam), 
    sum(score_1)/sum(exam), 
    sum(score_2)/sum(exam), 
    sum(score_3)/sum(exam)
FROM student_scores
WHERE student_year = 2018 AND exam > 0
group BY student_year, student_id;
```

ROWS look like this:

```
STUD_YEAR STUD_ID SCORE0 SCORE1 SCORE2 SCORE3 EXAM
2018      21354   17     21     19     25     1
2018      21354   22     19     0      23     1
2018      21354   0      0      0      0      0
2018      67864   10     15     10     20     1
```

So for student 21354
the calculation would be

```
(17+22+0)/(1+1+0), (21+19+0)/(1+1+0), (19+0+0)/(1+1+0), (25+23+0)/(1+1+0)
```

and the output would be

```
19.5, 20, 21.5, 24
```

A side note to put it in context.
A student can sit several exams each year where each exam consists of 4 sections which are scored separately.

Comment: Take under consideration dividing by 0 :)

Comment: I did not consider that. I could just filter it out with "WHERE exam > 0", since exam must have a value 1 to indicate the student sat the exam.

Comment: Just add to the *where* clause to remove rows with EXAM = 0. IOW, ```AND EXAM <> 0```

Comment: MySQL is pretty efficient in doing calculations like this. I don't see a way to improve performance.

Comment: You can fetch the sums as separate columns so that `sum(exam)` is calculated only once and then do the divisions client-side.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with the performance of the current wuery?

Comment: Not really. Query runs in .047 secs for 391 records consistently. Does the query (as it is currently written) calculate "sum(exam)" 4 separate times for each record or just once per record, hence my question about writing it in a more efficient way?

Comment: I've edited the query in the question with "exam > 0" in the WHERE clause.